# Форматирование телефонного номера

Tags: php

Как из

> 79817778833 **<-(int)**

сделать

> +7(981)777-88-33  **<-(string)**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
$str = strval(79817778833);
$str = '+'.substr($str, 0, 1).'('.substr($str, 1, 3).')'.substr($str, 4, 3).'-'.substr($str, 7, 2).'-'.substr($str, 9, 2);
```

=)

Answer (score 10):

Можно реализовать преобразование формата на базе регулярных выражений. Это позволит вам не возиться со смещениями символов в строке в явном виде.

Если говорить о коде, то он может иметь вид:

```
$in = 79817778833;
$out = preg_replace(
    '/^(\d)(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/',
    '+\1(\2)\3-\4-\5',
    (string)$in
);

echo($out);
```

А вот и [рабочий пример](http://ideone.com/yvLCNW) на IDEOne.

**Замечание**

Исходное число в вопросе может быть помещено в переменную типа int не в каждой сборке PHP. А зависит это от максимального значения целочисленных переменных (см. [`PHP_INT_MAX`](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-int-max)). Если значение вашего "числа" больше `PHP_INT_MAX`, то у вас могут быть проблемы. Поэтому, я бы рекомендовал вам хранить исходные данные как строку, а не как число.

Answer (score 6):

Можно и так:

```
$ph = 79817778833;
$ph = (string) $ph;
$ph = '+' . $ph[0] . '(' . $ph[1] . $ph[2] . $ph[3] . ')' . $ph[4] . $ph[5] . 
        $ph[6] . '-' . $ph[7] . $ph[8] . '-' . $ph[9] . $ph[10];
```

Работает минимум в 2 раза быстрее чем в других ответах.

Comment: Почему не так $ph = strval(79817778833); ?

Comment: скорость работы. [ссылка](http://leifw.wickland.net/2009/08/performance-of-converting-integer-to.html)

Answer (score 0):

Держи еще один простой способ одной строчкой и не мучайся:

```
<?php 
$MOBILE = "79817778833";        
echo preg_replace("/(\\d{1})(\\d{3}|\\d{4})(\\d{3}|\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})$/i", "+ $1 ($2) $3 $4 $5 $6", $MOBILE);
?>
```