# Получить "красивую" строку с номером(PHP)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Допустим имеется строка с номером вида `79167364857`. Каким способом можно привести её к виду ,например, `+7 (916) 736-48-57`, но так же, чтобы работало не только для `916`, а для любого кода регионов России? Может есть какие-то штатные решения для PHP? Или регулярка. Или всё же "шагать" от последнего символа вручную?

P.S. Во всех приведенных ссылках ответ только для кода из 3-х символов.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549517/%d0%a4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/574437/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

+7 - это код Российской Федерации.

В других странах количество цифр в номере отличается. Поэтому универсального решения добиться сложно.

Пример из вопроса можно сделать через регулярку

```
$p = '79167364857';
$s = preg_replace('#(\d)(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})#', '+$1 ($2) $3-$4-$5', $p);
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549517/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0#answer-549531

Comment: Внутри одной страны может отличаться кол-во цифр в коде (города) и непосредственно номере.

Comment: `(\d){3}` или `(\d{3})`?

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо, поправил.

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант подошел если ориентировать на Российские номера:

```
$phone = '79167364857';

if(preg_match( '/^(\d)(\d*)(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/', $phone,  $matches))
{
    $result = '+7 ('.$matches[2].') '.$matches[3].'-'.$matches[4].'-'.$matches[5];
}
//Output: $result = +7 (916) 736-48-57
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708248/formatting-phone-numbers-in-php)

Либо вариация из предыдущего ответа,также учитывающая код города:

```
$p = '89167364857';
$s = preg_replace('/^(\d)(\d*)(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/', '+7 ($2) $3-$4-$5', $p); 
//Output: $s = +7 (916) 736-48-57
```

Для 2,4 и.т.д символов так же работает:

```
$a = '84967364857';
$s = preg_replace('/^(\d)(\d*)(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/', '+7 ($2) $3-$4-$5', $p); 
//Output: $s = +7 (4967) 736-48-57
```

Comment: Что будет неправильно для какого-нибудь телефона г. Подольск, выглядящего +7(4967)333-222

Comment: @andy.37, ну, вместо `{3}` можно тогда использовать `*`

Comment: нельзя. `\d*` просто возьмет все цифры

Comment: @andy.37, По крайне мере, если использовать `^` и `$`, то в данном случае, так как не статичная часть только одна, она будет просто растягиваться. Проверял и на 2х, и 3х, и 4х знаках в коде.